# "Back to..." vs "back in..."

Tags: word-choice

Are they interchangeable? For example, in a situation like this? If not, how do they meaning differ?

> Back **to** the hotel, we changed into our swimming suits and sat
>   in the pools with the wine coolers we found in the fridge.
>
> Back **in** the hotel, we changed into our swimming suits and sat
>   in the pools with the wine coolers we found in the fridge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Back to the hotel" doesn't work in your sentence.

It works in something like:

> Rendezvous / Frankfurt - Page 76 Ilona Cole - 2009
>
> Before **going back to the hotel**, we did some Christmas shopping along
>   the Theatiner Gasse, with all its beautiful and elegant shops.

"**going to**" shows **movement towards a point**, thus "to the hotel" is correct here.

Answer (score 0):

Back to: sorry, this one is incorrect.

Back in: this one is fine.

You could also say: Back at....